# Client.Timeout running Docker in Fedora 37

Tags: docker, fedora-37

I have recently installed Fedora 37 (KDE) and tried to install Docker. I followed the instructions at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/fedora/.

When run `sudo docker run hello-world` I get a timeout with the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I am not behind any proxy, but I did disable IPv6 (based on [this discussion](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/network-very-slow/73157/6)) because I was having some slow internet problems.

I did see people having similar issues, but most of them are behind a proxy which I am not, and since I am new to Fedora (Linux) I am not sure if it has something to do with the IPv6 being disabled.

I have tried Windows Docker Desktop on the same machine and it's working fine with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try Podman instead of Docker and it was still the same.

What worked for me with Podman was I added values in the hosts file in /etc folder. I did `nslookup` for docker.io and got 3 IP addresses and added them there. For all the subdomains within docker.io I used the same IP address in the hosts file. Maybe this would have worked with Docker as well, but didn't further experiment with it. Sample values from my hosts file looks like this:

34.194.164.123 registry-1.docker.io 
52.1.184.176 auth.docker.io 
18.215.138.58 index.docker.io

Hope this helps others as well. Still not sure why I had to manually add them there.